# SNMP - Getting information from a process

Tags: windows, snmp, process-monitoring, zenoss

I need to setup a process monitor on a number of servers using a monitoring tool called Zenoss. The problem I'm facing is how can I get information on a specific process via SNMP? I'm not familiar with SNMP at all and I'm having trouble finding out what I need.

I've been trying to use a tool called SNMP-Probe but it only seems to give basic system information, nothing that I need or can use.

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to query the [hrSWRunTable](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1) in order to gather the information you need. This MIB gives you a lot of information such as process name, path, type, status, parameters, CPU and RAM usage even though those two informations are stored on another MIB ([hrSWRunPerfEntry](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1)). However how you do that "query" depends on the environment you're using, I am almost sure that vbs includes an SNMP library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example retrieval via NetSnmp from a Linux host. *(I would have added this as a comment on the accepted answer from @raz3r, but I wanted ability to format the text!)*

```
 snmptable -v2c -Ci -c public myserver  HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunTable
SNMP table: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunTable

 index hrSWRunIndex       hrSWRunName               hrSWRunID                        hrSWRunPath                                                                                                                  hrSWRunParameters hrSWRunType hrSWRunStatus
     1            1            "init" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                       "/sbin/init"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
     2            2        "kthreadd" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                         "kthreadd"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
     3            3     "ksoftirqd/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                      "ksoftirqd/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
 // other rows snipped for brevity
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just working on the same thing

snmpwalk -v2c -c public xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2

HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName

Comment: For tables, NetSnmp's snmptable gives friendlier formatted output than a snmpwalk.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find out exactly how to do this. I ended up going with a vbs script on each machine to find the misbehaving process and kill it automatically.